# Playing an array of mp3 files

Tags: javascript, audio, settimeout, playback

I have an array of mp3 files (`randomSelection`, randomly generated from a pool of 72 files) that I need to play one after each other and properly timed.
I'm using the following function which seems to work decently locally but not reliably when on the web (and totally unusable on mobile!).
How could I control the timing better or what better method could I use?
I'm not using Web Audio API, perhaps that would do a better job?

```
function playSong() {
  i = -1;
  (function f() {
    i = (i + 1) % 72;
    let menuet = randomSelection[i];
    let audio = new Audio(menuet);
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(f, 2250);
  })();
}
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could you add a language tag?

Comment: Done. Sorry about that! 